# OfficeWriter data marker for sheet name

Tags: officewriter

We only have the Template DLL v.8 installed, we use Microsoft SSIS v.2008R2 to process the data and then use a script task to bind the data to a template.

I have a need to produce a workbook with multiple sheets, the sheet names need to be dynamic.
Can you use a data marker on the sheet name?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You mention version 8, but you don't specify if it is 8.0 or you have a minor version of v8.

Either way this feature was introduced in v8.5.0 of ExcelWriter.

See the [OfficeWriter Change lo](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/OW8/Change+Log)g that states:

> ExcelTemplate allows data markers in tab names of XLSX/XLSM files

For more specific documentation on using datamarkers in sheet tabs see [SoftArtisan's documentation](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW9/Using+Data+Markers+in+Sheet+Tabs)

Just realize the Excel Sheet names have limitations that Excel controls, such as max number of characters, so you by limited in the data marker names you can use. One way to get around that issue would be to use ordinal syntax.